# How to getting ajax promise by the head of response only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, api, ember.js

To put it simply:
I need to handle the response from rails API to make something, but I need the header of response only, without any of data.

But `then` is not getting the response when it contains the header only.

## In details:

### rails Controller action:

```
def index
  # some logic here ...
  head :created
end
```

### ember component action:

```
let adapter = getOwner(this).lookup('adapter:application');
adapter.ajax(
  adapter.buildURL('/index'), 'POST', { some_param: 'some_content' }
).then(() => { 'do something here...' });
```

So in this implementation `{ 'do something here...' }` is never used.
But it works successfully if change the controller-action:

```
def index
  render json: [], status: :created
end
```

but I do not need to render some of json in response.

### So, the question is:

how can run code `'do something here...'` for controller-action:

```
def index
  head :created
end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can access the response data from API using, `.then((response) => { console.log(response) });`

Comment: nope. I tried it

Comment: To make my understanding clear: Your rails API returns only headers for the request you make and you need to access those headers. Did I get it right?

Answer (score 0):

why route it through the adapter at all? in general you should only use the adapter for `ember-data` requests.

Just use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) (use [`ember-fetch`](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-fetch) if you need a polyfill)!

```
const res = await fetch('/index', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({ some_param: 'some_content' }),
});

console.log(res.headers.get('your-header'));
```

Comment: coz we have logic for build url: `adapter.buildURL('some logic here')`

Comment: That's probably the wrong place if you don't build a data url. But you could just use adapter.buildURL and then pass that to fetch instead of adapter.ajax.